# Rename an existing file before replacing it in an Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I've got the following script...

```
[Files]
Source: "extractor.prop"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

How can I say, if `extractor.prop` already exists, rename it to `extractor.prop.old` and install this one?  By default at the moment it just deletes the old file so I don't want to erase the file if it's currently in use on a customer's site.

Comment: You'll need to use the[code] section, and write some Pascal script in order to do that.

Comment: Another alternative is to warn the user before InnoSetup overwrites an existing user-modifiable config file as such in `[Files]` using `Flags: confirmoverwrite uninsneveruninstall`. We declare this file as uninstallable by InnoSetup uninstaller. This give the user option to continue or cancel InnoSetup overwrite operation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use another `[Files]` entry with the `external` flag:

```
[Files]
Source: "{app}\extractor.prop"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "extractor.prop.old"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist
```

This is what `external` does:

> `external`
>
> This flag instructs Inno Setup not to statically compile the
> file specified by the Source parameter into the installation files,
> but instead copy from an existing file on the distribution media or
> the user's system. See the Source parameter description for more
> information.

([source](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection))

Comment: That's a great idea.  Much better than writing some pascal script.  +1

Comment: strange enough this work for me but when I added multiple lines of the same for 2 other files I want to check, it first renamed only the first file and not others and now it is not renaming any of the files I want to replace. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was, I was not setting the `DestDir` correctly, it should be the same as the `source` except the file name. Because my working directory was undefined, it worked sometimes but not other.

Comment: Great idea. But this solution COPY file not RENAME